# Definition of Subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I understand the definition of subsequence depends on the definition of sequence, however, I would like to have a most general or well-received definition of sequence and subsequences.

This question is mostly concerned with the infinity of subsequence. Since Wikipedia page regarding subsequence denote the example of subsequence with finite one, but contrary to this, it looks subsequences are considered as infinite mostly.

Comment: A sequence is an indexed (countable) set.  A sub sequence is a subset with relative order maintained.  Is that not specific enough.  (One could go on for,pages about what indexing exactly is).

Answer (score 1):

Given a sequence $\{a_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ a subsequence is defined by 
$b_{n}=a_{k_{n}}$ where $k_1 < k_2 < ....$ is an increasing sequences of indices.

A sequence  is really just a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ where X is a topological space you are mapping to. In this way you connect it to the way you typically view sequences by $a_n=f(n)$.

An even more general notion of a sequence is a net. Moreover, every is sequence is a net.
Given a directed set I with a binary relation a net is a function $f: I \to X$ where X is a topological space.

It is not hard to see the above stating that every sequence is a net is true, as the natural numbers are directed with the usual order.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is just a list of objects that are indexed by some indexing set.  The indexing set could be finite, could be countably infinite (like the natural numbers), or could be uncountably infinite (like the real numbers).  A subsequence $S$ is just a sequence whose elements are all part of some other sequence $T$.  In this case we would say $S$ is a subsequence of $T$.

As hinted at above, sequences (and therefore subsequences) don't have to be infinite.  Even on the [wiki page for sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence), it says:

> The number of elements (possibly infinite) is called the length of the sequence.

The reason we mainly focus on infinite sequences in math is because those are the interesting ones.  With infinite sequences we can ask questions about convergence, i.e., we can ask about $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n$.  And we can use infinite sequences to build infinite series, another interesting object.

Finite sequences are inherently less interesting because, well, they're finite and therefore easy to exhaustively study.  With finite sequences it doesn't make sense to talk about $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to+\infty} b_n$, because there's a "last" term and sending $n$ to infinity doesn't make sense.  And with finite sequences, we can build only finite sums, a (generally) less interesting concept than an infinite sum.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite sequences are maps from the natural numbers into a target space.

Example:

$s : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $n \to \frac{1}{n+1}$

Usually for sequence you are not so formal, and you can say

Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence defined by $s_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $ n>0$. For what we are doing, starting the sequence indexing at $0$ or $1$ is of no consequence.

To take a sub-sequence of $s_n$, by definition, you have a strictly increasing function

$\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and the subsequence is defined as

$x_{\sigma(n)}$

Note that for every natural number $n$, $\;\sigma(n) \ge n$. So, intuitively, the subsequence is 'moving faster' than $x_n$, as it can skip over stuff. You might also come out and say

Let $s_m$ be a subsequence of $s_n$

and if you are literate in this subject, you won't take offense.

In our example here, you can easily see that the sequence converges to 0, but you need a formal definition of the concept if you want to be serious.

Comment: How you find the inequality: For every natural number $n$, $\;\sigma(n) \ge n$.

Comment: @Helena You can use induction for a formal proof. But if you think of your sequence as $(x_0, x_1,x_2, \dots)$ you can imagine creating a sub-sequence by using check marks above the sequence listing to select the terms of the 'faster converging' sub-sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much.